# creating bargraph with 2 variables on ggplo2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar graph showing the count of some variables I grouped from a table using quintiles. I want this bargraph to be segmented by gender (it's in the data).

So it should look show me the prejudice cut and how often it is showcased in the data segmented by the gender.

```
prejiducequint = quantile(dta.sub2$WHPREJUDICE6R,seq(0,1, length = 5))
prejiducecut = cut(dta.sub2$WHPREJUDICE6R, breaks = incomequint)


        p = ggplot(dta.sub2, aes(prejiducecut, fill = FEMALE6)) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge")
        p
```

here is the data

```
WHPREJUDICE6R    prejiducecut FEMALE6
1          -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
2           0.075      (0.0275,1]       0
3           0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
4           0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
5          -0.020 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
6           0.130      (0.0275,1]       1
7           0.090      (0.0275,1]       0
8           0.230      (0.0275,1]       0
9           0.100      (0.0275,1]       1
10          0.870      (0.0275,1]       1
11         -0.130 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
12         -0.010     (-0.0125,0]       1
13          0.005      (0,0.0275]       0
14         -0.010     (-0.0125,0]       1
15         -0.060 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
16          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
17         -0.010     (-0.0125,0]       1
18          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
19         -0.075 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
20          0.005      (0,0.0275]       1
21         -0.010     (-0.0125,0]       0
22         -0.060 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
23          0.500      (0.0275,1]       0
24          0.020      (0,0.0275]       0
25          0.135      (0.0275,1]       0
26         -0.055 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
27         -0.440            <NA>       0
28          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
29         -0.065 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
30          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
31          0.035      (0.0275,1]       1
32         -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
33          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
34         -0.290 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
35          0.005      (0,0.0275]       1
36          0.300      (0.0275,1]       0
37          0.005      (0,0.0275]       1
38          0.070      (0.0275,1]       1
39         -0.195 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
40         -0.260 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
41         -0.040 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
42          0.720      (0.0275,1]       0
43          0.045      (0.0275,1]       1
44          0.125      (0.0275,1]       1
45          0.035      (0.0275,1]       0
46          0.005      (0,0.0275]       1
47          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
48          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
49          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
50          0.010      (0,0.0275]       1
51          0.495      (0.0275,1]       1
52          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
53          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
54          0.010      (0,0.0275]       0
55         -0.015 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
56         -0.110 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
57          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
58          0.065      (0.0275,1]       1
59          0.255      (0.0275,1]       1
60         -0.020 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
61          0.070      (0.0275,1]       1
62          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
63          1.000      (0.0275,1]       0
64          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
65          0.490      (0.0275,1]       0
66         -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       1
67          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
68          0.010      (0,0.0275]       1
69          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
70         -0.065 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
71          0.005      (0,0.0275]       0
72         -0.065 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
73          0.060      (0.0275,1]       0
74          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
75          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
76          0.155      (0.0275,1]       0
77         -0.190 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
78          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
79         -0.065 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
80          0.005      (0,0.0275]       1
81          0.060      (0.0275,1]       0
82         -0.100 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
83          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
84          0.005      (0,0.0275]       0
85          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
86          0.300      (0.0275,1]       1
87         -0.070 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
88          0.430      (0.0275,1]       0
89         -0.060 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
90         -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       1
91          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
92         -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       1
93          0.015      (0,0.0275]       0
94         -0.205 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
95          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
96          0.045      (0.0275,1]       0
97         -0.075 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
98          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
99          0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
100         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
101         0.235      (0.0275,1]       0
102        -0.060 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
103         0.505      (0.0275,1]       0
104        -0.185 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
105         0.185      (0.0275,1]       0
106        -0.115 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
107         0.005      (0,0.0275]       0
108        -0.440            <NA>       1
109        -0.100 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
110         0.430      (0.0275,1]       1
111        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
112         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
113         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
114        -0.120 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
115         0.005      (0,0.0275]       0
116         0.145      (0.0275,1]       0
117         0.110      (0.0275,1]       0
118        -0.010     (-0.0125,0]       0
119         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
120        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
121        -0.060 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
122         0.120      (0.0275,1]       1
123        -0.240 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
124        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
125         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
126        -0.060 (-0.44,-0.0125]       0
127        -0.305 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
128         0.050      (0.0275,1]       0
129         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
130        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
131        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
132         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
133        -0.045 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
134        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       0
135         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
136        -0.065 (-0.44,-0.0125]       1
137         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       1
138         0.055      (0.0275,1]       0
139         0.020      (0,0.0275]       1
140         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
141         0.000     (-0.0125,0]       0
142        -0.005     (-0.0125,0]       1
143         0.005      (0,0.0275]       1
```

The graph gets made, however, there is segmentation w/ gender (FEMALE6). Female 6 is a variable with either 0 or 1 based on the persons gender.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Data is now shown.